# Changing location of segue produces black screen in ios simulator

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I have no idea what is happening. In my interface builder, I had a segue pointing to the default viewcontroller and everything was fine. I added another viewcontroller to IB, changed the segue to point to it for when the app launches, and no now everything in the ios simulator is black.

Any ideas? I changed no code.

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a navigation controller (as the root controller), the first view controller in the stack should have a relationship (root view controller) segue from the navigation controller, otherwise your app won't know which view controller to load (first).

If the segue between the navigation controller and the first view controller is any other kind of segue (push, modal, custom), no view controller will load, and you will see a black (empty) window under the navigation bar.

If this is the case, delete the segue between the navigation controller and the first view controller, then CTRL-drag from the navigation controller to the first view controller, and for the segue type, choose `relationship`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped me